# Kivy Label not updating text

Tags: python, json, kivy, label, onpress

I have a refresh function that I want to use throughout my kivy app:

```
        for i in range(7):
            num = ((-(i * 2) + 12) + (self.today.weekday() * 2)) % 1
            try:
                self.top_half_layout.__getattribute__('children')[num].test = list(self.storage.get(date.fromordinal(self.today.toordinal() + i).isoformat()).values())[0]
            except KeyError:
                print('No Key for this day : refresh method :', date.fromordinal(self.today.toordinal() + i))
```

This process of getting the label object from the 'children' attribute worked in another part of my app within a on_press function for one of my buttons. But I want this refresh method to be dropped anywhere. The code runs and draws from the storage (json file) just fine but it doesn't update the label.text. I have tried texture_update() on the label object and have tried do_layout() on all of the parent objects of the label object and nothing seems to update it. What is the difference between this method and the one that was working in my on_press method.

Note: I no longer have the on_press method that was working because I later decided that is implementation of a refresh function worked better for my purposes.

EDIT: I tried pasting the code from my refresh function where the refresh function would be called and it isn't working there either (even though I know for sure I had it working earlier this week). I have no idea why the text isn't showing up on the actually app because after inspecting the label object with the debugger the **text** was changed.

Comment: What part of the code are you expecting to change a Label's text? Is `test` a typo?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was a typo, I typed test, not text. I spent like 3 hours pulling my hair out for this one simple problem.